# How to create a filter referencing a sheet name in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I create a filter that will allow me to change which sheet I am referencing in a query or filter function?

I want to be able to change the drop selection of on a main lookup sheet and have it change the sheet that it is referenceing.

Anythoughts? I am trying indirect function but I am hitting wall with errors.

=filter(indirect("'"&A2&"'"),(INDIRECT(A2&"!A:A))=B2)")))

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(
       indirect(A2&"!A:C"),
                           indirect(A2&"!A:A")=B2
       )
```

- *again it will throw `#N/A` error if `Cell_B2` value is not found in the `Column_A` of the tab you are referring to via `indirect()`*

Comment: Thank you, how can I add two other filters? I have values in D2 and E2 that I need to filter by. I need to first filter by B2 then D2 then E2.